# Array list of abstract class?

Tags: java

I am wondering how I can create an array list of classes that extend certain abstract class. Lets say I have abstract class:

```
abstract class Product{
}
```

and some class that extends it:

```
public class Toy extends Product{
}

public class TV extends Product{
}
```

I would like to implement a list of classes that extend abstract class `Product`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify _an array list of classes_?

Comment: I would like to have an array that will store multiple products.

Comment: Unless you have some specific methods you are trying to override, then TV and Toy are more like instances of a Product, than needing to be classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
final List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This means that you have a `List` of types that `extends` or `implements` `Product`.

You should **not** use:

```
List<? extends Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because `list.add` will be a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

It this what you are looking for?

```
List<? extends Product> list
```

Comment: Exactly! THanks so much!

Comment: @uksz `List<Product>` will also work in every case - the `? extends` is not necessary in this case. This is only necessary in a method _receiving_ a `List` of a specific type.

Comment: In fact the `? extends` is most likely harmful in this case.

Comment: It depends on the usecase. It Also could be implemented as generic `<T extends Product>` which is much better or just `List<Product>` as @BoristheSpider suggested.

Comment: @SergheyBishyr both those examples are for a `List<Toy>` _or a_ `List<TV>`, and you not knowing which you have. In this case, it is certainly the **wrong** approach, as the OP wants a `List` than can contain **both** `Toy` and `TV`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider as I understand from the question, it's not about the list that can contain all of the subclasses. So, `<? extends Product>` is ok if you want to be able to receive both `List<TV>` and `List<Toy>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I meant receive as argument in some method. E.g. `doSomething(List<? extends Product> list)`.  In this case you can pass both `List<TV>` and `List<Toy>` to `doSomething`